# System.IndexOutOfRangeException?

Tags: c#, arrays

I'm making a little database program and I've ran into an error System.IndexOutOfRangeException when trying to initialise past [currentIndexPlayer, 2] before that everything runs fine. How is it possible that I have ran out of space within the array?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication5
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        string[,] playerArray = new string[19, 7]; // Initial player array is declared, this is where the players are stored//
        int currentIndexPlayer = 0;

        private void addNewPlayerBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        { 
            if (addNewPlayerBtn.Text == "Add New Player")
            {
                playerFirstNameBox.ReadOnly = false; //Unlock all fields for input//
                playerIgNameBox.ReadOnly = false;
                playerSecondNameBox.ReadOnly = false;
                contactStreetBox.ReadOnly = false;
                contactTownBox.ReadOnly = false;
                contactPostcodeBox.ReadOnly = false;
                contactEmailBox.ReadOnly = false;
                contactTelephoneBox.ReadOnly = false;

                addNewPlayerBtn.Text = "Confirm"; 
            }
            else if (addNewPlayerBtn.Text == "Confirm")
            {
                if ((playerFirstNameBox.Text != "") && (playerIgNameBox.Text != "") && (playerSecondNameBox.Text != "")) // Validation check to see if all main fields were entered
                {
                    playerArray[currentIndexPlayer, 0] = playerFirstNameBox.Text;
                    playerArray[currentIndexPlayer, 1] = playerIgNameBox.Text;
                    playerArray[currentIndexPlayer, 2] = playerSecondNameBox.Text;
                    playerArray[currentIndexPlayer, 3] = contactStreetBox.Text;
                    playerArray[currentIndexPlayer, 4] = contactTownBox.Text;
                    playerArray[currentIndexPlayer, 5] = contactPostcodeBox.Text;
                    playerArray[currentIndexPlayer, 6] = contactEmailBox.Text;
                    playerArray[currentIndexPlayer, 7] = contactTelephoneBox.Text;
                    currentIndexPlayer++;

                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Missing fields","Problem With Input", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1); //Validation failed, display error message//
                    addNewPlayerBtn.Text = "Confirm";
                }

                addNewPlayerBtn.Text = "Add New Player";

                playerFirstNameBox.ReadOnly = true; //lock all fields for input again//
                playerIgNameBox.ReadOnly = true;
                playerSecondNameBox.ReadOnly = true;
                contactStreetBox.ReadOnly = true;
                contactTownBox.ReadOnly = true;
                contactPostcodeBox.ReadOnly = true;
                contactEmailBox.ReadOnly = true;
                contactTelephoneBox.ReadOnly = true;

            }
        }

        private void searchToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Form2 searchForm = new Form2();
            searchForm.Show();
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Array indexes are zero based.In this line you are trying to set seventh element but the last is 6

```
playerArray[currentIndexPlayer, 7] = contactTelephoneBox.Text;
```

Also you need to make sure `currentIndexPlayer` is equal to or less than `18` which is the size of the first dimension.

Answer (score 1):

It's probably that your array:

```
 string[,] playerArray = new string[19, 7];
```

Creates seven spaces in the second dimension yet later on you try to assign to the eighth space:

```
playerArray[currentIndexPlayer, 7] = contactTelephoneBox.Text;
```

Try changing that seven in the initialization to an eight and see if that works.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check that currentIndexPlayer < 19 before: playerArray[currentIndexPlayer, 0].